# Image editor with Zenity

Tags: bash, zenity

Is it possible to create simple image editor (draw line or something) using zenity (or maybe similar tool) and bash? I have searched many pages but i didn't even find the way how to show image in dialog using zenity.

Comment: What is it that you would like to do? Do you want to create new images? Or edit existing ones? What features do you need specifically? A list of start and endpoints and you want to draw straight lines? Or you want to replace all blacks with pinks? Please try and give a better clue as to what you want.

Comment: I wanted to create new images and draw on them like in paint, but now i think that it is not possible to do this just using command tools.

Comment: Draw would be something like: click on image -> old dialog shutdowns -> new dialog opens with dot in that place (this is how dots would be drawing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to create simple image editor (draw line or something) using zenity (or maybe similar tool) and bash?

No. zenity is a simple shell tool to display dialog boxes. It has none of the features that you'd need to build an image editor.